# Getting length of a drawn line with cv2 - python

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to get the length of a line i drew with cv2 on an image, how can i do it?

this is my code so far:

```
import cv2

refPt = []
image = cv2.imread('img.jpg',1)

def click_draw(event, x, y, flags, param):
    global refPt
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        refPt = [(x, y)]
        print(refPt)

    elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        refPt.append((x, y))
        cv2.line(image, refPt[0], refPt[1], (255, 0, 0), 2)
        cv2.imshow("image", image)
        print(refPt)


cv2.namedWindow("image")
cv2.setMouseCallback("image", click_draw)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**refpt** contains the cords for the clicked points.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `norm` function between the two points (the default norm is L2, that is what you need):

```
cv2.norm(refPt[0],refPt[1])
```

Comment: Thank you! i will try it now

Comment: when i try to use it, i get an error:
**IndexError: list index out of range**

Comment: then it has just one value (or zero) are you sure it contains coordinates?

Comment: yes, for example:
firstly: [(1080, 374)]
and then after: [(1080, 374), (1417, 677)]

Comment: i also tried another way:


```size1 = (refPt[1][0] - refPt[0][0])**2 + (refPt[1][1] - refPt[0][1])**2
    size2 = math.sqrt(size1)
```
but it gives the same error

Comment: you can use it only after cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP because otherwise you will have just a point and you cannot compute any distance (that's zero)